# Base 64 logic isn't appropriate

Tags: python, django-views

I'm trying to figure out a situation were in Django using pycharm where I'm trying to decode a Base64 entity to Hexa decimal but I'm not getting the appropriate one

Views.py

```
def analyze(request):
djtext = request.GET.get('text', 'default')
result = ''
result= base64.b64decode(djtext).hex
params = {'purpose': 'DECODE ENCODE', 'analyzed_text': result}
return render(request, 'Result.html', params)
```

I'm just accepting the data from text area and trying to call the b64decode method.
Input: Gv/gxXeYoUGwdw5zAP/xJg==
Output: 1affe0c57798a141b0770e7300fff126
Output which I'm expecting: c5e0ff1a-9877-41a1-b077-0e7300fff126

Comment: The endianess is wrong: for every block of 32 bits, the bits are "swapped"

Comment: It however looks like here the *encoding* is the culprit, since encoding the `c5e0ff1a-9877-41a1-b077-0e7300fff126` produces: `b'xeD/Gph3QaGwdw5zAP/xJg=='`.

Comment: I just tested it via http://guid-convert.appspot.com/ and I did B64 to Hex and Hex to B64 which gives me the correct value that I posted above.